# Connection between two definitions of expected value

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Then the expected value of $X$ is defined by

$$EX := \int X\,dP$$

Now in undergraduate probability we're often given a distribution function (or the density function)

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x)\,dx$$

to describe a distribution. In this case we say that $X$ has distribution function $F(x)$ and define

$$EX = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx.$$

Since the first definition is supposed to be the most general one, how do we derive the second definition from the first? The second definition doesn't even explicitly give out the random variable $X$ as a measurable function nor even clearly specify what the probability measure is, although I assume it must somehow be the Stieltjes measure defined by extending $P((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$.

Anyone care to elaborate on this?

Comment: How about writing $\int_{x} xf(x)$ as $\int_{x} xDF(x)$?

Comment: Yes, I can see this, but why the arbitrary integrating over the random variable $x$, i.e. the identity function? Where does that come from or is it just the definition?

Comment: To be more precise, one often sees language like "let X be an exponentially distributed random variable". What does this even mean? What is the random variable X as a measurable function? Why would the expectation then suddenly just be the integral over the identity function over the Stieltjes measure of its distribution function? It all seems like an arbitrary way of connecting the definitions.

Comment: I addressed this exact topic in my blog post here: https://justanothermathblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/probability-theory-2/

Answer (score 2):

This goes by the lovely name of  "[Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)".